# Should I power off a wireless device when changing an external antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking, power, antenna

Currently I am using a a wireless router (Asus RT-N12) and Wireless USB adaptor (TL-WN722N). Both of these have removable external antennas (RP-SMA connectors).

I want to know the correct and safe way to change an antenna on a wireless device.

Should I power of the device first? 
Will changing an antenna while the device is running damage the antenna and/or hardware?

I'm quite new to wireless technology and have minimal background with electronics.
I did a quick search on the web but didn't find any answers to my question.

Comment: Yes!!  Do power down the device.

Comment: I've certainly done that before. No observable damage.

Comment: @StBlade, I thought that would be the logical thing to do. But Do you have any references to backup what you said?

Comment: @suit.  I always play it safe when it comes to any hardware components where electricity is involved.  A small imperceptible short is enough to damage any electronic device.  Static electricity when you touch something is close to 2000 volts, enough to fry a RAM module.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to turn off the equipment. You can safely change the antenna when router is turned on.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm the maximum power of wi-fi is only 200mW, so its too low to short-circuit something.

> To attach the ANT24-0700C antenna, remove the default detachable antenna from the wireless access point or router, and connect the ANT24-0700C antenna to the RP-SMA receptacle of the
>   wireless device

Comment: This is indeed what my intuition and experience says, but I'd like to see some "hard evidence" here nevertheless. Or at least a schematic of a typical receiver circuit.

Comment: I agree with Jan Dvorak. Say, if I put a 18dBi Yagi antenna on a 1000mW Alfa wireless adaptor would that have any potential to harm the device?